# Comparing two UITextField, == vs ===

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `UITextField` instances and upon update I need to figure out which one is updated, usually I'd use `===` to check reference identity, but accidentally put `==` instead and it worked. So I wonder if `UITextField` conforms to `Equatable` and what actually are involved in comparison?

To illustrate:

```swift
let textFieldA = UITextField()
let textFieldB = UITextField()

textFieldA.text = "A"
textFieldB.text = "B"

print("A.text", textFieldA.text)
print("B.text", textFieldB.text)
print("A == A:", textFieldA == textFieldA)
print("A == B:", textFieldA == textFieldB)
print("A === B:", textFieldA === textFieldB)

textFieldB.text = "A"

print("A.text", textFieldA.text)
print("B.text", textFieldB.text)
print("A == A:", textFieldA == textFieldA)
print("A == B:", textFieldA == textFieldB)
print("A === B:", textFieldA === textFieldB)
```

Output:

```
A.text Optional("A")
B.text Optional("B")
A == A: true
A == B: false
A === B: false
A.text Optional("A")
B.text Optional("A")
A == A: true
A == B: false
A === B: false
```

So `==` and `===` works the same regardless of whether their text are same or different, I wonder what is happening under the hood?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITextField` is a subclass of `NSObject`, and `NSObject` [conforms](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject#conforms-to) to `Hashable`, which means it also conforms to `Equatable`.

`NSObject.==` is implemented by delegating to `isEqual`, and the default implementation of `isEqual` compares object identities. See the code in [NSObject.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/9f53cc551e065d73b327a80147895822bc8f89e0/Sources/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L4) in the swift-corelibs-foundation implementation,

```
public static func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isEqual(rhs)
}

open func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    guard let obj = object as? NSObject else { return false }
    return obj === self
}
```

And frankly, that is the only reasonable implementation of `NSObject.==` I can think of.

Evidently, `UITextField` did not override `isEqual`, and so comparing with `==` produces the same result as comparing with `===`.

Answer (score 2):

`UITextField` extends `UIControl` -> `UIView` -> `UIResponder` -> `NSObject` which conforms to the `NSObject` protocol.

`NSObject` conforms to `Hashable` which extends `Equatable`.

Ultimately the Swift `==` operator is going to call the `isEqual:` method that `UITextField` inherits from `NSObject`. The default implementation of this is to simply compare the pointer.

`UITextField` does not override `isEqual:` to compare the `text` property or any other property. So the end result is that `==` and `===` are effectively the same in this case.

Use `===` when you only care about if the two references are to the same object. Don't use `==` just because it gives the same result in this case. It's possible that could change in some future update.